# Connecting to CosmosDB from Docker container

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to learn Docker and am building up a solution slowly as I go. I created an Azure Function App that has one Http endpoint exposed. I created the Docker file to build and run the solution in a linux container(image:`mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0`, Debian image). I'm on a Windows machine.

I installed the Azure CosmosDB Emulator on my Windows machine and wanted to connect to it from the function app running in the linux container.

I am passing in the connection string for cosmos as an environment variable.

```
ARG COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING="AccountEndpoint=https://host.docker.internal:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
```

I'm trying to connect to the emulator through the following code:

```cs
    await new CosmosClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureCosmosConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
        .GetContainer("db_name", "container_name")
        .UpsertItemAsync<Dto>(dto)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When I do this, I'm getting the following error(I assume the first few lines are the most relevant, but am including the rest in case I'm wrong):

```
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.HttpRequestMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.GetDatabaseAccountAsync(Uri serviceEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.GetDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync(Uri defaultEndpoint, IList`1 locations, Func`2 getDatabaseAccountFn)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.InitializeReaderAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosAccountServiceConfiguration.InitializeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.InitializeGatewayConfigurationReaderAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.GetInitializationTaskAsync(IStoreClientFactory storeClientFactory)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.EnsureValidClientAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.EnsureValidClientAsync(RequestMessage request)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(Uri resourceUri, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType operationType, RequestOptions requestOptions, ContainerInternal cosmosContainerble`1 partitionKey, Stream streamPayload, Action`1 requestEnricher, CosmosDiagnosticsContext diagnosticsContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.ProcessItemStreamAsync(Nullable`1 partitionKey, String itemId, Stream streamPayload, OperationType operationType, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, CosmosDiagnostiiagnosticsContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.ExtractPartitionKeyAndProcessItemStreamAsync[T](Nullable`1 partitionKey, String itemId, T item, OperationType operationType, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, CosmcsContext diagnosticsContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.UpsertItemAsync[T](T item, Nullable`1 partitionKey, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

When I look at the emulator locally in my browser, it is using a `localhost` certificate(I assume one created with the dotnet cli).

**Attempt 1**
Export the localhost cert as a `.pfx` file and then get the linux container to trust that through the following commands(in my Dockerfile)

```
ARG CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD="Test|234"
RUN openssl pkcs12 \
-in "/src/localhost.pfx" \
-clcerts \
-nokeys \
-out "/src/localhost.crt" \
-passin pass:${CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
RUN cp "/src/localhost.crt" "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/"
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

I assume this attempt doesn't work, at least in part, due to the fact that the certificate on the Windows machine is created for `localhost`, whereas to connect to it from docker, the address needs to be `host.docker.internal`.

**Attempt 2**
Add the exported certificate to the Kestrel process running the function app in hopes that it would then honor it by adding the following to my dockerfile
`ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/src/localhost.pfx`

**Attempt 3**
Update the `CosmosClient` instantiation to include options overriding the `HttpClientFactory` as follows:

```cs
CosmosClient = new CosmosClient(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureCosmosConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process),
                new CosmosClientOptions
                {

                    HttpClientFactory = () =>
                    {
                         using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
                         {
                             httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
                             return new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                         }
                    }
                });
```

With every attempt above, I'm still seeing the same error. Not sure what else to try to get this to work...

Just found [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1232) on GitHub. Seems as though I'm not alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thank you to [Matias Quaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta) for all of the useful documentation. I had already pored over most of it before receiving his answer, but really appreciate all the time it took to compile it.

I have been struggling with this for around two weeks now and finally got something that I think will work. This work is largely based on the script found in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1232#issuecomment-632942023). I found that there is a PowerShell module that gets put on your computer when you install the Cosmos DB Emulator, so I tried to leverage those functions as much as possible to do the work.

The script's entry point is the function `Start-CosmosDbEmulatorForDocker` and it

1. Makes sure the Emulator is stopped.
2. Generates a new certificate to be used with the Docker image and replaces the one that was created upon install of the emulator.
3. Generates a `.pfx` certificate from the one created for the emulator.
4. Restarts the emulator once the new certificate is ready.

The password taken by the function is the one used for the `.pfx` file generated.

`azureCosmosDbEmulator.ps1`

```bsh
using namespace System.ServiceProcess

Function Start-CosmosDbEmulatorForDocker(
  [Parameter()]
  [securestring]
  $password
) {
  $cosmosDbInstallLocation = Get-CosmosDbInstallLocation
  If (!$cosmosDbInstallLocation) {
      Install-AzureCosmosDBEmulator
  }

  Write-Host "Importing Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator powershell module."
  Import-Module -Name "$($cosmosDbInstallLocation.InstallLocation)\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"

  Install-CosmosDBDockerCertificate -cosmosDbInstallLocation $cosmosDbInstallLocation.InstallLocation -password $password

  Start-CosmosDbEmulator -AllowNetworkAccess -Key "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
}

Function Get-CosmosDbInstallLocation() {
  Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Azure Cosmos DB Emulator" } | Select-Object InstallLocation
}

Function Install-AzureCosmosDBEmulator() {
  Write-Host "Installing Azure Cosmos Db Emulator."
  $installer = "$PSScriptRoot\cosmosEmulatorInstaller.msi"
  curl "https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-emulator" -O $installer
  Start-Process -Wait -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, $installer
  Remove-Item $installer
}

Function Install-CosmosDBDockerCertificate(
  [Parameter()]
  [string]
  $cosmosDbInstallLocation,

  [Parameter()]
  [securestring]
  $password
) {
  If ((Get-CosmosDbEmulatorStatus) -ne [ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped) {
    Write-Host "Stopping Cosmos DB emulator."
    Stop-CosmosDbEmulator
  }

  $dockerCertificatesPath = Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent) "certificates"
  $cosmosDbPfxCertificatePath = "$($dockerCertificatesPath)\cosmosdbemulator.pfx"
  Uninstall-Certificate -dockerCertificatePath $cosmosDbPfxCertificatePath

  Write-Host "Generating new Cosmos DB certificate to work with Docker."
  New-CosmosDbEmulatorCertificate "host.docker.internal"
  Start-Sleep -s 5

  New-DockerCertificate -dockerCertificatePath $cosmosDbPfxCertificatePath -password $password

  Set-Location (Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent)
}

Function Uninstall-Certificate(
  [Parameter()]
  [string]
  $dockerCertificatePath
) {
  Write-Host "Removing existing DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate certificate."

  if (Test-Path $dockerCertificatePath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $dockerCertificatePath
  }
}

Function New-DockerCertificate(
  [Parameter()]
  [string]
  $dockerCertificatePath,

  [Parameter()]
  [securestring]
  $password
) {
  Write-Host "Generating new pfx version of DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate certificate for use in Docker image."

  Get-CosmosDbEmulatorCertificate | Export-PfxCertificate -Filepath $dockerCertificatePath -Password $password
}
```

I then have a shell script to be run inside the Docker image that will install the `.pfx` cert into the Docker container. The `COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX_PASSWORD` value must match the one used by the PowerShell script.

`trust_cosmos_db_emulator_crt.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Save current working directory
PWD=`pwd`
pushd $PWD

# Find and move to the location of this script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX=$1
else
    COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX="/certificates/cosmosdbemulator.pfx"
fi
COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX_PASSWORD="SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD"
CERT_TO_TRUST="cosmosdbemulator.crt"

# Generate .crt file if pfx exists
if [ -f "$COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX" ]; then
    openssl pkcs12 -in $COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX -clcerts -nokeys -out cosmosdbemulator.crt -passin pass:$COSMOS_DB_EMULATOR_PFX_PASSWORD;
fi

# # Trust Cert (will end located in /etc/ssl/certs/ based on *.crt name as a *.pem, e.g. /etc/ssl/certs/cosmosdbemulator.pem for cosmosdbemulator.crt)
if [ -f "$CERT_TO_TRUST" ]; then
    cp $CERT_TO_TRUST /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
    update-ca-certificates
    rm $CERT_TO_TRUST;
fi

# Restore working directory
popd
```

The project structure I have is as follows:

```
src/
  scripts/
    azureCosmosDbEmulator.ps1
    trust_cosmos_db_emulator_crt.sh
  certificates/
  DockerFile
```

The Dockerfile contains the following lines:

```
COPY ["/scripts/", "/scripts/"]
COPY ["/certificates/", "/certificates/"]
RUN /scripts/trust_cosmos_db_emulator_crt.sh
```

With all of that in place, I can build the docker image with `docker build -t temp .` and then run it with `docker run -it -p 80:80 temp` and the code running inside of the docker container will talk to my local machine's installed version of the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator.

As this was a HUGE pain in the neck, if you are experiencing this pain as well, vote for better support from Microsoft on this [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030/suggestions/18533509).

Comment: This post took about an hour to configure for my specific requirements, having spent 3 days previously trying to get it to work through other sources, I stumbled on it. Should be in the MS docs. Love your work.

Comment: @SeanStanden Thanks so much. So glad it worked for you too! Like I said, this was a few weeks of work, but I'm glad it could benefit others also.

Answer (score 7):

## Update (2/10/2021)

The SDK now allows overriding SSL validation in an easy fashion (reference https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21#disable-ssl-validation):

```
CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    HttpClientFactory = () =>
    {
        HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
        };

        return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
    },
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
};


CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, authKey, cosmosClientOptions);
```

## Older information

Reference:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1551#issuecomment-634365001
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-mac-or-linux

### Step 1 - Export the Certificate

Following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates), but the certificate needs to be a **PFX**, not CRT. It will ask you to set some password.

### Step 2 - Place the cert somewhere you can copy or access from docker

For example, I put it on a folder I can map to when booting Docker along with the code I wanted to run:

[image]

### Step 3 - Get your machine's IP address

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-mac-or-linux, I used `ipconfig` and got my Windows IP.

### Step 4 - Start a docker image

In my case, I use one with the NET Core 3.1 SDK, the official one from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images

I started the container with an interactive shell, and mapping `localhost` to the IP I got on Step 3. This let's you **use localhost in the connection string**.

`docker run -v /c/DockerSample:/DockerSample --add-host="localhost:192.168.1.15" -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /bin/bash`

And I'm also mounting the folder where I saved the project and the certificate I want to import. This is not required, but I'm not fluent on Docker to know if there is a better way to pass the certificate.

After the shell starts, I basically run the commands described in the [Emulator doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#linux) and the certificate gets added.

[image]

#### Step 5

The Docker container should now have the required Cert to connect to localhost and you should not need the HttpClientFactory.

NOTE: Also there is a bug tracking HttpClientFactory not being used everywhere that is the source of your error https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/1548

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. Unfortunately I couldn't get the solution working as you proposed, but the below is working for me.

Comment: It works with "CosmosClient" but what about the v3 "DocumentClient". It does not have a ignore ssl error options.

Comment: Side note: If running in minikube, use the minikube ip versus the local system.