# How to bypass SSL and access cosmosDb emulator from docker container running a .net core app?

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm attempting to connect to the cosmosDb emulator installed locally on my windows machine via a docker container running a .net core webapi project.

Unfortunately I get the following error as soon as the container starts...

`Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`

The reason why appears to be detailed in this [thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1232) however the proposed solution at the end doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm attempting to use CosmosDb with Entity Framework Core. My `Startup.cs` code looks like the following...

```cs
services.AddDbContext<EventCatalogCosmosDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseCosmos(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CosmosConnection"),
    Configuration["CosmosDb:DatabaseName"].ToString(), cosmosClientOptions => new CosmosClientOptions()
    {
        HttpClientFactory = () =>
        {
            HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (req, cert, chain, errors) => true
            };
            return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
        },
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
    })
);
```

After attempting to build my image and running it with the following command...

`docker run -d -p 3000:80 -e "ConnectionStrings__CosmosConnection=AccountEndpoint=https://host.docker.internal:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==" --name myapp aspnetapp`

I still get the error above.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you run the app outside of Docker with an account endpoint of https://localhost:8081/ does it work then?

Comment: Also check this part of the docs. Your Docker container is considered a different machine, so you need to configure CosmosDB to allow connections from the network.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#enable-access-to-emulator-on-a-local-network

Comment: Does this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173426/connecting-to-cosmosdb-from-docker-container/62416581#62416581) help?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment ooof.....I better clear my schedule for the week before digging into that!

Comment: @HansKilian It does work if the app is run outside of docker

Comment: @Konzy262 Its big. Took me weeks to find a solution. I wouldn't run any code from the internet without perusing it, but dropping those scripts in your solution should do the trick. It is a pain, but there is a link for a Microsoft issue at the bottom to help encourage them to make this less painful in the future. Best of luck!

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Ta. I may try digging through it. As well as local development I was hoping to run some tests in a pipeline with my real app running against the emulator. You would think it was easy......