# Issue with HTTPS connection to CosmosDb Emulator in Linux Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

[A new Linux emulator for CosmosDb](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/build-2021-apps-at-any-scale/) was recently announced.

I'm using Docker for Windows. And there is a problem with the connection to CosmosDb Emulator in Linux Docker Container via ASP.NET Core.

The Docker container with the emulator launched successfully and I can reach the explorer by: `http://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`

[image]

Then I run the project in Visual Studio and get that problem

> The SSL connection could not be established

[image]

I've tried to install a certificate from [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator#install-certificate) but my host is Windows and it doesn't work for me.

Could you please suggest how to install the certificate for Linux container on Windows host?

Comment: Since you are using .NET, have you tried disabling SSL validation as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#disable-ssl-validation ?

Comment: Actually, I think it could be one of the resolving. But it unacceptable for production  environment.

Comment: Emulator is not for production environment either, the same way you are having a configuration that is targeting the Emulator, you can make that configuration trigger a different client initialization for the dev environment.

Comment: I tried the solution that you propose. But still have the same issue. (Disabled ssl validation in startup)

Comment: Even after disabling SSL as the documentation shows (setting client to Gateway also), you still get `The SSL connection could not be established` ?

Comment: I am using EF. As I understood it's not support all option\settings for cosmos. I would try to use connection to sdk without ef, maybe than it could work.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173426/connecting-to-cosmosdb-from-docker-container#answer-62416581

Answer (score 2):

You have to download certificate from Docker container to your host machine and install it (PowerShell):

```
#Download certificate from container
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://$($ipAddress):8081/_explorer/emulator.pem -Method Get | Out-File "$($env:TEMP)/emulatorcert.crt"

#Import certificate
$cert = Import-Certificate -FilePath "$($env:TEMP)/emulatorcert.crt" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```